# python program Remove duplicate string with sequence of number without using pandas DataFrame

Tags: python

**Replace a csv file duplicated string with sequence of numbers WITHOUT using PANDAS DATAFRAME**

> python
>   I have a csv file that contain 4 column i want to replace a string of all the column with a sequence of number if any duplicate will be there then it should give the prevoius number.for that i have written this code which return a three dicts:dict1,dict2,dict3 now i want to print that dictionary value in a file like given in below fig.

```
with open(tempFile, 'r', encoding="utf8") as csvfile: 
    # creating a csv reader object 
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        next(csvreader, None)
        firstRow = next(csvreader)

        NameCount = 1
        AddressCount=1
        EmailCOunt=1
        input_dict={firstRow[1]:NameCount}
        input_dict2={firstRow[2]:AddressCount}
        input_dict3={firstRow[3]:EmailCOunt}

        dict1={firstRow[0]:NameCount}
        dict2={firstRow[0]:AddressCount}
        dict3={firstRow[0]:EmailCOunt}

        for row in csvreader:

            value = input_dict.get(row[1])

            if value is None:
                NameCount = NameCount + 1
                input_dict.update({row[1]:NameCount})
                dict1.update({row[0]: NameCount})
#                 input_dict2.update({row[2]:counter})
#                 dict3.update({row[0]: counter})

            else:
                input_dict.update({row[1]: value})
                dict1.update({row[0]: value})
#             
#                 input_dict2.update({row[2]: value1})
#                 dict3.update({row[0]: value1})
#             value = input_dict2.get(row[2])

            value1 = input_dict2.get(row[2])
            if value1 is None:
                AddressCount = AddressCount + 1
                input_dict2.update({row[2]:AddressCount})
                dict2.update({row[0]: AddressCount})
            else:
                input_dict2.update({row[2]: value1})
                dict2.update({row[0]: value1})

            value2 = input_dict3.get(row[3])
            if value2 is None:
                EmailCOunt = EmailCOunt + 1
                input_dict3.update({row[3]:EmailCOunt})
                dict3.update({row[0]: EmailCOunt})
            else:
                input_dict3.update({row[3]: value2})
                dict3.update({row[0]: value2})

        print('dict1-', dict1)
        print('dict2-', dict2)
        print('dict3-', dict3)[this is the image of my input csv file in which i have replaced the duplicated string of col 1,2,3 with seq no. by using dicts[this is how i need my output look like after string replacement][1]  ][1]
```

This is the input data which is written in csv file:

```
job_Id  Name        Address     Email
1   snehil singh    marathalli  ss@gmail.com
2   salman      marathalli  ss@gmail.com
3   Amir        HSR     ar@gmail.com
4   Rakhesh     HSR     rakesh@gmail.com
5   Ram     marathalli  r@gmail.com
6   Shyam       BTM     ss@gmail.com
7   salman      HSR     ss@gmail.com
8   Amir        BTM     ar@gmail.com
9   snehil singh    Majestic    sne@gmail.com
```

and the required ouput which i'm not able to get is:

```
job_Id  Name    Address Email
1          1       1    1
2          2       1    1
3          3       2    2
4          4       2    3
5          5       1    4
6          6       3    1
7          2       2    1
8          3       3    2
9          1       4    5
```

please help........

Hello guys i tried with this way its working..

```
count=1
            iter_obj1 = iter(dict1.values())
            iter_obj2= iter(dict2.values())
            iter_obj3 = iter(dict3.values())
            while True:
                try:
                    element1 = next(iter_obj1)
                    element2 = next(iter_obj2)
                    element3 = next(iter_obj3)
                    s = count, element1, element2, element3
                    print(s)

                    with open("snehil.csv", 'w') as f:
                        f.write('\n')
                        f.write(json.dumps(s)+'\n')
                        f.write(line)
                    count=count +1
                except StopIteration:
                    break
```

and the output is :

```
(1, 1, 1, 1)
(2, 2, 1, 1)
(3, 3, 2, 2)
(4, 4, 2, 3)
(5, 5, 1, 4)
(6, 6, 3, 1)
(7, 2, 2, 1)
(8, 3, 3, 2)
(9, 1, 4, 5)
```

This is the correct output but i'm not able to print it in csv file its only showing the last row (9, 1, 4, 5) its means its reading all the data in single line..for print this i have used:

```
with open("snehil.csv", 'w') as f:
#f.write('\n')
f.write(json.dumps(s)+'\n')
```

even i tried it with Dataframe also to print it into csv file but give a error like: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'values'
for dataframe i have written like:

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(s, orient='index')
print(df)
```

please help me how to get it in csv file and print all the rows in differnt cell...thanks

**Program to read the csv file and replace the string with squence of number and write it to csv file**

```
import csv
import os 
from io import StringIO
# tempFile="input1.csv"

with open("input1.csv", 'r') as csvfile: 
    # creating a csv reader object 
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        next(reader, None)

        data = {}
        for row in reader:
            for header, value in row.items():
                try:
                    data[header].append(value)
                except KeyError:
                    data[header] = [value]

        for key in data.keys():
            values = data[key]

            things = list(sorted(set(values), key=values.index))

            for i, x in enumerate(data[key]):
                data[key][i] = things.index(x) + 1

        with open("snehil.csv", "w") as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            # Write headers
            writer.writerow(data.keys())
            # Make one row equal to one value from each list
            rows = zip(*data.values())
            # Write rows
            writer.writerows(rows)
```

while excuting this program i got an error:

```
for header, value in row.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

please help me i don't understand why i got this error......

Comment: In this program i'm not able to print the output as i shown in fig2.. i.e can't able to replace string with number..

Comment: Please include all relevant information within your question through editing instead of posting additional comments.

Comment: use `csv.DictReader` instead of `csv.reader()`

Comment: thanks a lot... i got the ouput...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read your `csv` as a `dictionary`, list values per key (column) and then use a set of unique values to index on.

First we read the data:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO("""
1,snehil singh,marathalli,ss@gmail.com
2,salman,marathalli,ss@gmail.com
3,Amir,HSR,ar@gmail.com
4,Rakhesh,HSR,rakesh@gmail.com
5,Ram,marathalli,r@gmail.com
6,Shyam,BTM,ss@gmail.com
7,salman,HSR,ss@gmail.com
8,Amir,BTM,ar@gmail.com
9,snehil singh,Majestic,sne@gmail.com""")
, delimiter=",", fieldnames=["job_Id", "Name", "Address", "Email"])
```

We then restructure the data to be a set of keys with list of values `{key_1: [], key_2: []}`:

```
data = {}
for row in reader:
    for header, value in row.items():
      try:
        data[header].append(value)
      except KeyError:
        data[header] = [value]
```

Next you want to give each value in each list a unique identifier.

```
# Loop through all keys
for key in data.keys():
    values = data[key]

    # Create a list of set to use as unique indexer
    things = list(sorted(set(values), key=values.index))

    # Loop through each value in columns
    for i, x in enumerate(data[key]):

        # Replace old value with unique index
        data[key][i] = things.index(x) + 1
```

---

**How to save `data` in a new csv-file?**

Since `csv.writerows()` takes a list but treats it as a row, we need to restructure our data so that each row is one value from each list. This can be accomplished using `zip()`:

```
with open("test.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    # Write headers
    writer.writerow(data.keys())
    # Make one row equal to one value from each list
    rows = zip(*data.values())
    # Write rows
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: I got it its printing the correct output but in a single line how to get a line breaker here where do i place it....?

Comment: `data` is a list of dictionaries. What do you want it to be? A new csv-file?

Comment: yes  i want to print in a new csv file....and it should print alll the data in row by row format...for now i'm getting a output with your program in a single column by print(data[key][i])

Comment: Edited the answer to do this. Don't forget to accept answer.

Comment: It worked thank a lot...one more thing if you don't mind u have hard coded the value in data what if i have a very large datasets then i want to read the csv file instead of writing all data.. so for that i used the : with open(tempFile, 'r', encoding="utf8") as csvfile: in my program...the problem is when i tried to write the same thing in program you have given its not working....sorry i'm creating a mess but i'm new to python so i'm not getting how to do it..

Comment: the values in data are not hard coded. what do you mean when you say that it is not working when you read the csv-file? which csv-file are you reading?

Comment: It was before when you have not given the code for writing csv file now i'm able to read it...thanks for that....but want to read the csv file by using : with open so i don't have to write it... i have csv file which contail 27 column like that i have to replace the string with number for duplicated value.. so for that i have created a small one to do the same implementation in the program

Comment: recently i have Edited the code and please see in my code and tell me why i'm getting that error while reading the csv file..